# Can't push_back a glm::mat4 element into a vector declared in a header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, glm-math

I have a vector delared in a header file `a.h`:

```
// in a.h
class A {
public:
    ...
    std::vector<glm::mat4> transforms;
}
```

I tried to `push_back()` an object into it in my `a.cpp` file:

```
// in a.cpp
glm::mat4 transform;
transforms.push_back(transform);  // errors here
```

but I'm getting these errors:

> no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty,
>   _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=glm::mat4, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)

and

> 'std::vector>::push_back': 2 overloads
>   have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

If I try to declare the vector directly inside the `a.cpp` file then it works:

```
// in a.cpp
std::vector<glm::mat4> foo;
foo.push_back(transform);   // this works
```

What is going on? What did I do wrong when I declared the vector in the header file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match

Focus on this, as this seems to be the problem. It means that you may have made something to do with the vector being or having applied to it a constant type qualifier in your A class. That is the best I can say without more information, as it is obvious that it is not the vector itself that has the problem.

For a clearer and more definite answer you might have to post the exact code you are using.

Comment: I declared the vector exactly like shown and I don't use/reference that vector anywhere yet, apart from the place that I'm getting the error in the .cpp file.

Comment: @Chin So you are sure the method the code is found in is not a const method?

Comment: that's the issue! I don't know why I missed it, thanks a lot!